# after postback of data to the dropdown the data is repeated

Tags: asp.net, dropdown

I've a form with textbox and two dropdowns. I am using this form for insert/details/edit of data. Initially for insert data, the form is working fine. But when I retrieve data from database, the dropdown values are repeated i.e., the retrieved value is repeated in the dropdown again.

My code::

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label><span class="required">*</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="200" runat="server" id="txtEmpName" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Gender</label><span class="required">*</span>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectEmpGender" runat="server" style="height: 34px;">
        <option value="0">MALE</option>
        <option value="1">FEMALE</option>
        <option value="2">UNKNOWN</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Marital Status</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectEmpMarried" runat="server" style="height: 34px;">
        <option value="0">BACHELOR</option>
        <option value="1">MARRIED</option>
        <option value="2">DIVORCED</option>
    </select>
</div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <asp:Button ID="btnAddFamMem" runat="server" Text="ADD" OnClick="btnAddFamMem_Click"  />
    </div>
</div>
```

I am showing the data from grid view on selectedIndexChange method as ::

```
protected void famGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gvr = famGrid.SelectedRow;
    txtEmpName.Value = gvr.Cells[1].Text == "&nbsp;" ? null : gvr.Cells[1].Text;
    selectEmpGender.Items[selectEmpGender.SelectedIndex].Text = gvr.Cells[2].Text == "&nbsp;" ? null : gvr.Cells[2].Text;
    selectEmpMarried.Items[selectEmpMarried.SelectedIndex].Text = gvr.Cells[3].Text == "&nbsp;" ? null : gvr.Cells[3].Text;
}
```

Please see the attached image, the image is of the data after I retrieved the inserted data from grid view for edit/details.

The retrieved value for `selectEmpGender` is UNKNOWN, it is repeated in the dropdown and the option MALE is not showing. Similarly, the retrieved value of `selectEmpMarried` is MARRIED which is repeating in the dropdown and BACHELOR option is not showing. Why is it so?

[image]

Comment: Why dont you use the `DropDownList`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter May I know what is the problem with `select`. In the actual project it is already implemented, changing all the dropdowns is not possible. I've presented here only sample of the problem. Thank You!

Comment: I just wanted to understand the reason for replacing a `WebControl` like `DropDownList` that you need to access at serverside with a pure html control. At client it's rendered the same, but you can assign a `DataSource` or handle it's `SelectedIndexChanged` event and many other things as well. It's simply making your life easier. Also, it stores it's state(what item is selected) in the viewstate by default.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am working in a old project where `select` already implemented. And we are having problem with it. But changing all the dropdowns will take time and is not feasible for now. So if I know the reason for the problem that will be much better. Thank You!

Comment: _"The retrieved value for selectEmpGender is UNKNOWN, it is repeated in the dropdown and the option MALE is not showing"_ It is always repeated and that's by design. The item that is selected is always shown on top and also in the list below. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select

Comment: @TimSchmelter ok the value is repeated, but why another value is not showing in the dropdown. In the first dd why MALE is not showing and in the second dropdown why BACHELOR is not showing? I tried with `asp:DropDownList` still getting the same problem. Please can you try once. Thank You!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174390/discussion-between-user4221591-and-tim-schmelter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you dont want to change the text of the selected item but you want to select the corrrect item:

```
string gender = gvr.Cells[1].Text;
ListItem genderItem = selectEmpGender.Items.FindByText(gender);
if(genderItem != null)
    selectEmpGender.SelectedIndex = selectEmpGender.Items.IndexOf(genderItem);
// same for the other
```

Comment: Now I am getting the desired result. Please can you explain me what was the problem and how does your code solve it. That will be great help for me. Thank You!!!

Comment: @user4221591: if the currently selected item was not showing the text of the other gridview-cell, then you were changing the text of the wrong item which leaded to repeating texts. You just wanted to select the correct item.

Answer (score 0):

After inserting or updating employee details, clear drop-down and then bind its details.

Comment: After inserting,
txtName.Text = string.Empty;

Answer (score 0):

```
After inserting,
txtName.Text = string.Empty;
selectEmpGender.SelectedIndex = -1;
selectEmpMarried.SelectedIndex = -1;

While editing,
bind datas from genderItem 
selectEmpGender.SelectedItem.Value= genderItem.gender;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.